# mongodb $and Operation for $lte and $gte not working as expected for Integer value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I have created the following aggregation pipeline which fetches data from two collections based on certain filters. The main table being Allocation:

```
    {
   "aggregate":"Allocation",
   "pipeline":[
      {
         "$match":{
            "$and":[
               {
                  "allocPush.weekNum":{
                     "$gte":202109
                  }
               },
               {
                  "allocPush.weekNum":{
                     "$lte":202114
                  }
               },
               {
                  "statusCode":{
                     "$in":[
                        "C",
                        "L"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "$lookup":{
            "from":"Drug",
            "localField":"articleId",
            "foreignField":"_id",
            "as":"drugData"
         }
      },
      {
         "$unwind":"$drugData"
      },
      {
         "$sort":{
            "articleId":1,
            "sapStoreNum":1,
            "batchNum":1,
            "allocPush.weekNum":1
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

In my Allocation Collection I have an embedded Doc called allocPush which is a list of object.

I have an allocation document that has two allocPush documents like so:

[image]

One has a weekNum value of **202107** and the other **202117**

In my aggregation pipeline I have an $and condition that verifies that it needs to fetch documents that have the **allocPush.weekNum** value between **202109** and **202114**

but this aggregation still fetches the record that has allocPush.weekNum values **202107** and **202117** (Neither of which are between 202109 & 202114)

[image]

When I change the values of weekNum for both the allocPush docs to just **202107** or both to **202117** it doesn't fetch that record

Not sure why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `$elemMatch`.

These query criteria

```
               {
                  "allocPush.weekNum":{
                     "$gte":202109
                  }
               },
               {
                  "allocPush.weekNum":{
                     "$lte":202114
                  }
               }]
```

are applied to the entire document.  Since the document contains an `allocPush.weekNum` that is greater than `202109` and the the document also contains one that is less than `202114`, the document as whole satisfies both conditions.

What you probably meant to check was that a single element of the array is between those two values.  `$elemMatch` allows you to specify criteria that must be satisfied by a single element of the array in order for the document to match.

That might look something like:

```
{
    "allocPush": {
        "$elemMatch":{
            "weekNum":{
                "$gte":202109, 
                "$lte":202114
            }
         }
     }
}
```